# When to do property specific tasks after xml deserialization

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization, xml-serialization

I'm using XML deserialization to handle XML responses from an api I'm calling. One of the properties I'm getting back needs to be changed depending on another property in the class. An example:

```
<XmlRoot("Foot")> _
Public Class Foo
    Private m_bar1 As String
    Private m_bar2 As String
    Private m_rawbar2 As String

    <XmlAttribute("Bar1")> _
    Public Property Bar1() As String
        Get
            return m_bar1
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_bar1 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <XmlAttribute("Bar2")> _
    Public Property RawBar2() As String
        Get
            return m_rawbar2
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_rawbar2= value

            'This won't (always) work because the order in which the 
            'properties are deserialized is unknown
            'm_bar2 = m_bar1 & m_rawbar2 
        End Set
    End Property

    <XmlIgnore()> _
    Public ReadOnly Property Bar2() As String
        Get
            return m_bar2
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

In my case bar1 would be an url and bar2 would be a relative path on the same domain. The only time I can set m_bar2 would be when every property is deserialized since the order is unknown. What would be the best way to do this?